# The degree of polynomial and dimension of vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I have a question about polynomial vectors that why dimension of the polynomial vector space have a dimension = $n+1$ ($n$ = degree). I mean why $P_2(\mathbb{R})=3$, but $P_2(\mathbb{R}^3)$? I think my question is most about the terminology. Like, if you have a basis that is $[p_1(x),p_2(x),p_3(x)]$, this basis should belongs to $\mathbb{R}^3$, but why you write $P_2(\mathbb{R})$. Or more specifically is there any intuition about the degree of polynomial and $\mathbb{R}$?

Update: Can I say the degree of polynomials has nothing to do with the the dimension of a vector space? For example, can a basis  $[p_1(x),p_2(x)]$ is in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking here. Why would a basis $\{p_1(x),p_2(x),p_3(x)\}$ for the polynomial space $P_2(\mathbb R)$ belong to $\mathbb R^3$? (Although, obviously $\mathbb R^3\cong P_2(\mathbb R)$ as $\mathbb R$-vector spaces)

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  A basis for the space of polynomials of degree up to $2$ has $3$ elements, e.g., {$x^0, x^1, x^2$}

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.  You'll get a lot more help if your posts are easy to read.

Comment: $P_2(\mathbb{R})$ is not the same thing as $P_2(\mathbb{R}^3)$; the latter would be “polynomials of degree at most three with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}^3$”.... which doesn’t actually make sense.

Comment: If you have a 10-story building, are floors 5, 6, and 7 the same as a 3-story building? While it is true that $P_2(\mathbb{R})$ has dimension $3$ (that is, $\dim(P_2(\mathbb{R})=3$), and that means it is *isomorphic* to $\mathbb{R}^3$, it does not mean that it is *the same* as $\mathbb{R}^3$. A basis for $P_2(\mathbb{R})$ will consist of elements of $P_2(\mathbb{R})$: polynomials of degree at most $2$ or the zero polynomial. For example, $\{1, x, x^2\}$.

Comment: It’s dimension $3$ because to describe a polynomial of degree at most $2$, I need to give you **three** pieces of information: the constant term, the linear term, and the quadratic term. We call the polynomial degree $2$ for other reasons, not because of how much information you need to specify one.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you! Can I say the degree of polynomials has no direct relationship with the the dimension of a vector space? For example a basis $[p_1(x)]$ is in R and a basis set $[p_1(x),p_2(x)]$ is in $\mathbb{R}^2$, but both belongs to $P_2(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: No, that’s nonsense. You are utterly confused. Nothing you wrote makes **any** sense.

Comment: Of course if a vector space $V$ has dimension $3$ you can always define another vector space $W$ of dimension $2$ such that a basis of $W$ contains only vectors from $V$; that is, $W$ is a subspace of $V.$ Therefore you can take any two polynomials of degree $n$ and say they are the basis of a vector space. But that does not make them a basis of the vector space of _all_ polynomials of degree $n.$ It isn’t true in general, and in the cases where it is true you need to do more work to show it.

Comment: @DavidK: I think you are missing “linearly independent” between “you can take any two polynomials of degree $n$” and “and say they are absis of a vector space”. (You also want “at most” before “degree”, perhaps?)

Comment: Please, yaw518, do not write an equation where there is a vector space on one side of the equals sign and a number on the other. If you mean **the dimension** of the space is three, then write that; don't write that the vector space itself equals three! You really, really, really have to be careful and precise with your use of mathematical language, or you will wind up with all kinds of confusions.

Comment: @yaw518 I recommend you read up more about vector spaces and bases. Your question clearly shows a lot of confusion on these subjects. "A basis set $[p_1(x),p_2(x)] $ in $\mathbb R^2$" is a meaningless statement.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes, I should have stipulated the vectors are independent, otherwise they are not a basis. The point was, OP’s two-dimensional space at the end of the question says little about anything else in the question.

Comment: If one of the answers has cleared things up for you, yaw518, let me encourage you to "accept" it by clicking in the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgive the bluntness, but your understanding of this topic is **broken**. You need to rebuild your understanding from the ground up. Unfortunately, this is not really the best forum for this, so I would advise finding a tutor (IRL) to help you understand this stuff. I'm going to do the best I can to try to set you right, but just know that there's only so much I can do over the internet.

We say that a vector space $V$ has dimension $n$ if it has a basis (a finite, linearly independent, spanning set) with $n$ elements. If a vector space has a basis of $n$ vectors, then *every* basis of the space has $n$ elements. If the vector space is over the scalar field $F$, then this means that the space is *isomorphic* to $F^n$ (the set of $n$-tuples of scalars), meaning that there is an invertible linear map $T : F^n \to V$.

The existence of such a linear map is very useful. It essentially means that we can look at $V$ in a different way. We get a perfect analogy for $V$ in the vector space $F^n$. It doesn't matter how abstract the objects in $V$ are, how computationally difficult the vector addition $+$ is, etc, we can "understand" the vector space $V$ by looking at corresponding operations in $F^n$.

The polynomials are a great example. Here we have $V = P_2(\Bbb{R})$, which is a set of functions from $\Bbb{R}$ to $\Bbb{R}$ that take the form $f(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2$ for some scalars $a_0, a_1, a_2$. **This is not a triple in $\Bbb{R}^3$**; this is a function. You can substitute any real number you like into it, to get another real number. That said, it's still a vector space over $\Bbb{R}$; it satisfies all of the vector axioms (for the usual function addition and scalar multiplication).

It has a basis $\{x \mapsto 1, x \mapsto x, x \mapsto x^2\}$. To establish this, we need to show that the set is spanning and linearly independent. It's spanning basically by definition of $P_2(\Bbb{R})$; every element of $V$ can be written as a function $x \mapsto a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2$, which is a linear combination:
$$a_0(x \mapsto 1) + a_1(x \mapsto x) + a_2(x \mapsto x^2).$$
Linear independence requires proof too. If we assume that we have a linear combination equal to the $0$ vector (the function $x \mapsto 0$), then
$$a_0(x \mapsto 1) + a_1(x \mapsto x) + a_2(x \mapsto x^2) = x \mapsto 0.$$
Equivalently, for any $x \in \Bbb{R}$,
$$a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 = 0$$
Trying $x = -1, 0, 1$, we get a system of linear equations,
$$\begin{matrix}
a_0 & - & a_1 & + & a_2 & = & 0 \\
a_0 & & & & & = & 0 \\
a_0 & + & a_1 & + & a_2 & = & 0,
\end{matrix}$$
which has only one solution: $a_0 = a_1 = a_2 = 0$. Thus, the set is linearly independent. We have a basis of three vectors, making $V$ isomorphic to $\Bbb{R}^3$.

What would be an example of an isomorphism between the two spaces? All you need to do is take a basis $\{v_0, v_1, v_2\}$ for $V$ and define
$$T : F^3 \to V : (a_0, a_1, a_2) \mapsto a_0 v_0 + a_1 v_1 + a_2 v_2.$$
In this case, using this particular basis,
$$T : \Bbb{R}^3 \to P_2(\Bbb{R}) : (a_0, a_1, a_2) \mapsto (x \mapsto a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2).$$

This means that we can understand polynomials via vectors of the coefficients of the various monomials. In this way, we build an analogy for $P_2(\Bbb{R})$ in terms of the more concrete $\Bbb{R}^3$. We don't have to worry about the various intricacies of a polynomial like $x \mapsto (x - 2)^2$ (its graph, its roots, its stationary points, its value at $\pi$, etc.) when we can just look at the analogous point $(1, -4, 4) \in \Bbb{R}^3$. That ordered triple contains all the information we need about the function in order to do vector arithmetic on it.

Think about how a computer might do vector arithmetic with polynomials. It has no capacity to store the infinitely many values that a function might take over the infinitely many values in $\Bbb{R}$. However, it can easily remember ordered triples of coefficients $(a_0, a_1, a_2)$, and add it to other ordered triples of coefficients. The computer doesn't have to store an entire function; it just remembers the ordered triple of coefficients, and adds/scalar multiplies the vectors as though they were points in $\Bbb{R}^3$.

However, as handy as the analogy is, remember: **the spaces are not the same!** One space helps us understand the other, but the two sets have not even a single element in common!

Hopefully that helps in some way.

Comment: thank you. your answer really cleared things up.

Answer (score 0):

Just because a vector space has dimension $n+1$ does not mean that it is $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. In this case, $P_n(\mathbb{R})$ has dimension $n+1$ because its minimal basis has $n+1$ vectors (the most obvious basis here is $1, x, x^2, \ldots, x^n$).

Comment: This answer, even short, really give me some insights about this. When I really think of polynomial this is crazy. I need someone explain this in geometry

Answer (score 0):

> Update: Can I say the degree of polynomials has nothing to do with the
>   the dimension of a vector space? For example, can a basis
>   $[p_1(x),p_2(x)]$ is in $\mathbb R^2$

If we you are dealing with the vector space $\mathcal P_n$, the standard basis of this vector space is $$\mathcal B_{\mathcal P_n} = \{1,x,x^2,x^3,...,x^n\}$$ I'm having trouble interpreting your question, but if your confusion is why, for instance, the dimension of $\mathcal P_3$ is $4$ rather than $3$, it's because polynomial degrees start at $0$, so the dimension of $\mathcal P_n$ is $n$ plus the $0$ term's contribution to make $n+1$.

The answer to

> can a basis $[p_1(x),p_2(x)]$ is in $\mathbb R^2$

is no. If I suppose $p_1(x)$ and $p_2(x)$ assume linear and quadratic functions respectively, $\mathcal B_{\mathcal P_n}$ cannot be a valid basis because the elements of the basis do not live in $\mathbb R^2$ and therefore cannot span $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: $0$ is **never** an element of a basis.

Comment: My apologies! I mean to say that $0$ is the lowest degree, which is responsible for the $1$ in the basis.

Comment: Also, there is no such thing as **the** basis for a vector space.

Comment: You're right - I've edited my answer to *the standard basis* of $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: Good, but you still write **the basis** for the polynomial space.

Comment: You're right. I've fixed that now.